# Q promise resolve is not throwing catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, q, deferred

I am working on an integration with Fitbit using the fitbit-node module.

I got everything working except am stuck on token refresh.

Here is the fitbit refresh token code:

```
  refreshAccessToken: function (accessToken, refreshToken, expiresIn) {
    if(expiresIn === undefined) expiresIn = -1;

    var deferred = Q.defer();

    var token = this.oauth2.accessToken.create({
        access_token: accessToken,
        refresh_token: refreshToken,
        expires_in: expiresIn
    });
    console.log('got to token refresh')
    token.refresh(function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
            console.log('got to token refresh error')
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(result);
            console.log(result)
            console.log('got to token refresh resolve')
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
},
```

Then there s the then and catch statements. The catch statement seems to fire but the then staement never does:

```
  userfitbit2.refreshAccessToken(user[0].fitbitt, user[0].fitbitrt)
  .then(function (results2) {
    console.log(result2)
    console.log('got here2')
    const doc = {
      fitbit: result2.user_id,
      fitbitt: result2.access_token,
      fitbitrt: result2.refresh_token,
      fitbitlr: new Date.parse(result2.expires_at),
      updatedAt: Date.now(),
    };
    User.update({ _id: userid }, doc, function (err, raw) {
      if (err) {

      }

    });
  })
  .catch(err => console.log("error:", err.context.errors))
```

I am wondering why the promise is not throwing the then statement. Works everywhere else. The console.log from before and after the promise resolve do show and work.

Comment: Do you ever see it log out "got to token refresh resolve"?

Comment: A promise can either be _fulfilled_ or _rejected_, so either the _then_ callback is invoked, or the _catch_ callback is invoked. Here, if `userfitbit2.refreshAccessToken(user[0].fitbitt, user[0].fitbitrt)` has an error, only the catch callback will be invoked

Comment: I do see the got to token refresh resolved. But never get to the "got here 2" which I would expect. I'm unsure the causes of broken promise then call back returns. I see the error callbacks fine. @NicholasTower